# Proper way to encode arrayBuffer to Base64 and vice-versa

Tags: javascript, base64

I have this code:

```
var bufferPromise = e.data.arrayBuffer();
                    bufferPromise.then(function(array){
                        var base64chunk = _base64ArrayBuffer(array)
                        var base64_string = 'data:video/webm;base64,' + base64chunk
                        console.log(base64_string)
                        var arr = _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64_string)
                        sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(arr);
                        //sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(new Uint8Array(array)); // works!
                    })
```

Where I need to convert the `array` buffer in this code to be converted to base64, and in order to test if the base64 is indeed correct I need to convert the base64 back to `arrayBuffer` and then feed that into the `sourceBuffer` for display. The problem with this code is that the base64 is not working in fact it throws `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character` at the `_base64ToArrayBuffer` function.

```
function _base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binary_string = window.atob(base64);
    var len = binary_string.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(len);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        bytes[i] = binary_string.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return bytes.buffer;
}
```

My question is what is the correct *array to base64* function and what's the correct *base64 to array function*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base 64String contains `data:[<mediatype>][;base64],<data>` at the begining so you need to get everything else after that.

You can try this var myBase64 = `str.split('base64,')[1];` and then do your checks.

[You can read more here:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs)

Comment: Ah yes, I totally missed that one. Thanks.